# Trace of $2\times2$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

This is my thesis problem: Determine the number of $2\times2$ skew orthogonal matrix in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for $p>2$.

$A$ is skew orthogonal if $A^tA=-I$, where $A^t$ denotes the transpose and $I$ is the identity matrix.

I need to obtain the characteristic polynomial of a skew orthogonal matrix. Here's my findings:

$2\times2$ general form of characteristic polynomial: $x^2-\operatorname{tr}(A)x+\det(A)$.

$\det(A^tA)=\det(-I)$

$(\det A)^2=1$

$\det A= 1,-1$

But I don't know the trace of $A$ such that $A^tA=-I$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for $p>2$.

Comment: You should really compute the number for any dimension. Start by breaking into two cases: When $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ and when $-1$ is not. In the first case you can multiply $A$ by the square root of $-1$ and the counting is the same as the [orthogonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group#Over_finite_fields) $B^TB=I$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: From Cayley-Hamilton theorem you have

$A^2-\text{tr}(A)A+\det(A)I=0$.

Multiply both sides by $A^T$ to obtain

$(A^TA)A-\text{tr}(A)(A^TA)+\det(A)A^T= -A+\text{tr}(A)I+\det(A)A^T=0 $.

Hence $\text{tr}(A)I=A-\det(A)A^T$.

What conclusion can be made from this equation?

Comment: What is it sir? :)

Comment: From this you can see for example the sign of determinant as left side of equation is evidently symmetric..

Comment: Do you see now that $\text{tr}(A)I=A+A^T$ ?

Comment: Or it can be A-At if detA=1?

Comment: No, because $\text{tr}(A)I$  is symmetric matrix..

Comment: So the tr(A)=A +At ?

Comment: $tr(A)I=A+A^t$ where $I$ is identity matrix. We have matrices on both sides. $tr(A)$ is here a scalar.

Comment: Could you help me obtain the tr(A) if AtA=-I ?

Comment: Your matrix has evidently form $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{bmatrix}$, only in this case above equation is satisfied, additionally from the determinant you have $a^2+b^2=-1$..

Comment: I forgot that A is in Zp for p>2

Comment: @Widawensen When $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ we can have $A=xI$ with $x^2=-1\mod{p}$. In that case $det(A)=-1$. the equality $tr(A)I=A-A^T$ can perfectly happen, with $tr(A)=0$.

Comment: Then count your matrices taking into account above constraints..

Comment: Sir, may I contact you through email? :)

Comment: @JohnRexPerez I'm sorry John but we should here exchange remarks..

Comment: How can I obtain tr(A) such that AtA=-I in Zp for p>2?

Comment: @orolo You are right, $tr(A)=0$  gives $A=A^T$ and $-a^2-b^2=1$ from the form $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ b & -a \end{bmatrix}$